# Is making heavy use of localstorage a good practice?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently making a REACT web app, and I've made heavy use of localStorage to keep track of data without having to make more api calls, i'll provide a quick explanation of what i'm doing and would like to know if it's a good practice or if there's a better way.

I am working on a blog app and need to have access to some data in other components (such as the username of the currently connected user.)

So each time I make an api call, and receive data that I know I will need in other components (especially if it's not a child component of the one receiving the data), I store it in the localstorage so I can access it easily.

Is making use of the local storage everytime I need it for convenience good ?

Do you have any guidelines regarding when to query data instead of relying on localStorage ?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You should look into contexts (or Redux or some other state management thing de jour) instead. You can't subscribe to changes in localStorage, making updating your app's state hard when something in LS changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that localstorage is persistent data. So it should be used for data that is required when the user leaves your app and comes back to it again.

On the other hand, sharing data between components while your app is running should be done with other mechanisms, typically passing props from a parent component to child components. Also, you can use React context or Redux or similar APIs to store data that is required globally while your app is running.

Comment: the problem is when the page is refreshed, goodbye state.

Comment: @conterio Local storage won't solve that.

Comment: local storage can help solve that, absolutely it can.  The way I see it is, if you have an identity of some kind that's not anonymous send that data to persist on the server.  If the data is associated with anonymous save it in a session or local storage, or use some library.

Comment: @conterio You did read the first sentence of my answer, right?

Comment: I was responding to your response of "Local storage won't solve that", not your original answer. In reality local storage can solve refreshes, you said it won't.

Comment: so what was your first comment responding to?

Comment: The first sentence of your second paragraph.

Comment: @conterio I should back up. You are right that my first reply is inaccurate. That's what I ended up with after several edits. Are you suggesting that I change my answer? If so what part, and how should I edit it? Nothing in my answer says anything about state, so I am unclear how your comment relates to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would say "it depends"

If you are not accessing data in localStorage way too often, data inside of it are not changing frequently. Then it is OK. (still you need to have fallback for any other storage, try safari in anonymous window there localStorage does not work, old mobiles have limits how much data can be stored etc. etc.)

Otherwise it would be better use other means of storing data locally. Like IndexedDB, WebSQL. You can use some lib for managing those like for indexDB [dexie](https://dexie.org/), [idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) or  any other.

If you are using localStorage just to ease your work with react props drilling, then rather use React.context, flux, redux... or any other state managment lib.